I tried to write a procedure that checks the number of times a letter (within an array) occurs in another array
I tried to create a “love calculator” by checking the number of times the letters T, R, U, E, L, O, V, and E (both lowercase and uppercase) are found in two names. I wrote it in a procedure so I could reuse it. The code procedure checks the number of times a letter in the array is in one of the names. Furthermore, it multiplies the value of countT by ten (the amount of times the letters of the word true were found in the name) and transfers the new value into the variable percent. Furthermore, it adds the value of countL (the number of times the letters of the word love were found in the name).
Attached is the code:
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
    countT db 0
    countL db 0
    percent db 0
    len1 db 10
    len2 db 15
    name1 db 'C','i','n','d','e','r','e','l','l','a'
    name2 db 'P','r','i','n','c','e',' ','C','h','a','r','m','i','n','g'
    true db 't','r','u','e','T','R','U','E'
    love db 'l','o','v','e','L','O','V','E'
    yes_msg db "yes$"
    no_msg db "no$"
    string equ [bp+10]
    len equ [bp+8]
    count equ [bp+6]
    array equ [bp+4]
CODESEG
proc CmpArray
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov si, array
    mov cx, 8 
    ThroughString:
        push cx
        mov di, string
        mov cx, len   ; Reload the length of the string into CX
        ThroughArray:
            mov al, [si]
            mov bl, [di]
            cmp al, bl
            jne continue
            mov ah, count
            inc ah
            mov count, ah ; Store the updated count back to memory
        continue:
            inc di
            loop ThroughArray
        pop cx
        inc si
    loop ThroughString
    pop bp
    ret 8
endp CmpArray
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    push offset name1 ; Pass the offset of name1
    push offset len1  ; Pass the offset of len1
    push offset countT ; Pass the offset of countT
    push offset true ; Pass the offset of true
    add [countT], ah
    call CmpArray
    
    push offset name2
    push offset len2
    push offset countT
    push offset true
    add [countT], ah
    call CmpArray
    
    push offset name1 ; Pass the offset of name1
    push offset len1  ; Pass the offset of len1
    push offset countL ; Pass the offset of countT
    push offset love ; Pass the offset of true
    add [countL], ah
    call CmpArray
    
    push offset name2
    push offset len2
    push offset countL
    push offset love
    add [countL], ah
    call CmpArray
    
    mov al, 10
    mov bl, [countT]
    mul bl
    add al, [countL]
    mov [percent], al
    cmp [percent], 54
    jg is_greater
    jmp is_not_greater

is_greater:
    mov dx, offset yes_msg
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    jmp exit

is_not_greater:
    mov dx, offset no_msg
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    jmp exit
    
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start

For the names Cinderella and Prince charming the countT (the count for the “true” array) was supposed to be 6 and the countL (the count for the “love” array ) was supposed to be 5.
The code was supposed to print yes as the total percentage (which was supposed to be 65) is greater than 54. However, it prints no. I’ve tried debugging but I still don’t understand what went wrong.

What are the random add [countT], ah instructions supposed to do? Anyway, use your debugger to single step the code and see where it goes wrong.

I guess you wanted to update countT with the return value. It will work better if you do that after the call. Also you pass the address of a counter to the CmpArray which uses it as a value.
